# How do I call from a list of names?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I've only been learning java for a few weeks so I'm still a noob. I want the next line to print "mr/miss." + firstname + lastname;
however, i don't want to type the gender of the person in. I want there to be a list of male names (long list over 1000 names) and the program to detect if the firstname input is one of those male names. The program can then assign the correct title (mr/ms.)

How do I do this without making a normal arraylist and typing out each name individually (which'll take agessss).

Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, will you be checking out today? (Y/N)");
    String CheckOutYesOrNo = scanner.nextLine();

    if (CheckOutYesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) { x();}
    else if (CheckOutYesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {System.out.println("Okay then. Enjoy the rest of your stay at the Rizty Hotel!");}
    }

    public static void x(){
        System.out.println("Sure, would you mind telling me your last name?");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //how can I avoid making a new scanner?
        String lastname = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("And your first name?");
        String firstname= scanner.nextLine();





    }
}
```

Comment: What about names that could be either? (Bailey, Sam, etc.)

Comment: Have you the names in a .txt-file?

Comment: There's a reason that basically every system ever collects title – not just gender – from the user.

Comment: Have you thought about [unisex name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisex_name) ? What would you display in that case ?

Comment: "How can I avoid making a new scanner?"  Make the `scanner` a private member in your main class, instead of making it a local variable.  Then you'll need to access it with non-static methods, so your `main` will be something like `new MainClass().doMain()`, and your code will be in a non-static `doMain` method.

Comment: What do you mean that you're trying to avoid "typing out each name individually"?  If you have a list of names you need to check, somebody will have to type them in, either in your program, or into a file that your program will read in.  I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: Ahh, whoops didn't really think of unisex names.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a typical mapping. You could read all your names into a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) where the key is the name and the gender is the value. To resolve the gender just do something like `genderMap.get(name)`.